# Customize query method whose paramter is List in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I know Spring Data JPA has offered some query methods which can accept a list as its parameter like `List<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids)`.So how can I customize such methods? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IN. This accepts a collection of attributes.

```
List<T> findByIdIn(Collection<ID> ids)
```